# Is there a standards-compliant way to do zero-copy IPC in C++?

Tags: c++, ipc, type-punning

I have an application that currently reads data from a stream (socket, named, pipe, stdin, whatever) into a `char` buffer and then uses `reinterpret_cast` to point a `Foo *` (where `Foo` is a POD) into the middle of the buffer and then works with the contents of the buffer through that pointer.

Now, this breaks strict aliasing rules, though I doubt that it would actually cause a problem in practice. Still, is there an accepted way to do this in Standard C++? Because we're potentially transferring 100s of gigabytes this way, and do not want to, under any circumstances, introduce the overhead of copying this data out of the buffer into a structure with `memcpy`.

To be clear, the code looks something like this:

```
MessageData *msg = new MessageData();
while (ipc.we_have_data()) {
   ipc.read(msg);
   char *buf = msg->data();
   Header *h = reinterpret_cast<Header *>(buf);
   if (h->tag == 0) {
      Payload *p = reinterpret_cast<Payload *>(buf + sizeof(Header));
      do_stuff_with_payload(p);
   } else if (h->tag == 1) {
      // etc...
   }
}
```

I realize there may be alignment issues, but they do not concern me at this point. The data is being produced on the same platform by the same compiler, so there are no issues with the layout of structure members being different. But, as I understand it, this technically breaks strict aliasing rules.

Is there an efficient way to do this that doesn't break strict aliasing rules?

Or am I completely wrong, and it's just fine by these rules?

If so, why?

**Edit:** A deleted comment pointed to this [definition of the aliasing rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) that says `char *` gets a free pass. So, my example actually doesn't break strict aliasing rules. Does anybody know the right section of the standard for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the standard is not very friendly for processing structured data read into a buffer of characters. Only the opposite is allowed: if you know that you are going to read a POD object, you can build one and pass its address converted to a char pointer to any function that will be able to fill it with actual data, and then use it normally.

The *free pass* provided by `char *` only allows to process an object at a byte level, but the strict aliasing rule normally forbids to decide that a char buffer actually contains an object. Anyway, the higher risk here would be an alignment issue.

For the rest, specific implementations of compilers are perfectly allowed to ignore the strict aliasing rule. What happens then is undefined by standard but can be perfectly defined by a compiler provided you pass it the appropriate flag. Your program may then break with a different compiler or a different configuration of the same compiler, so it will have portability issues, but that may be acceptable provided it is clearly documented - and you are sure that no alignment issue may arise...

Comment: Alignment issues can often be dealt with efficiently.  Dealing with aliasing requires either using a compiler that can be relied upon to recognize certain obvious aliasing constructs, writing slow and inefficient code and hoping the compiler can maybe turn it into the sensible code one wanted to write in the first place, or writing code which compilers will hopefully not figure out how to break.  I'm not sure why some compiler writers seem deathly opposed to #1, since recognizing certain obvious constructs would seem easier than trying to make efficient code out of a standard-compliant mess.

Comment: @supercat - I'm not sure why either. This seems like something that should really be added to the C++ standard, an approved way to do certain kinds of aliasing. The ability to do things like that is part of the whole reason people use languages like C and C++ in the first place.

Comment: @Omnifarious: What makes the whole situation really sad is that if the Standard had simply given implementations permission to make aliasing assumptions when it *would make sense to do so*, and treated the fact that some implementations might not recognize certain kinds of aliasing as being somewhat analogous to the fact that some implementations may die if programs nest certain function calls 30 deep (or, for that matter, 3 deep), but suggest that quality implementations should handle whatever kinds of aliasing make sense given the target platform and application field...

Comment: ...common sense on the part of programmers and compiler writers could yield much better and more reliable results than the rules in the Standard which would, by any reasonable measure, be horrible if interpreted literally.  Not merely because they simultaneously block many useful optimizations while needlessly outlawing many useful constructs, but even moreso because they're ambiguous, there's no sane way to interpret them consistently, and no consistent way to interpret them sanely.

Comment: @supercat - My main issue with 'common sense' as such is that if it's left unspecified it makes it hard to write portable programs. I want a way that the standard promise will work. That way can be based on common sense, but I want it specified. It can promise that the exact result will be implementation defined behavior of course. It practically has to. But it can specify some loose boundaries on what that behavior is, the same way C99 does for type punning via unions.

Comment: @Omnifarious: Implementations which claim to be suitable for low-level programming should offer stronger behavioral guarantees than those which are targeted toward high-end number crunching.  The only way to accommodate such differences is either to have the Standard go into explicit detail, or leave such decisions to people who will know what makes sense for their target platform and application field.  A key principle should be that implementations may assume programmers aren't do anything "weird" if there's no evidence that they are, but be very cautious about optimizations...

Comment: ...in cases where such evidence exists.  The vast majority of aliasing optimizations involve the notion that if a compiler sees two accesses to the same lvalue and there is no evidence *between them* to suggest that anything else could access it, the accesses may be treated as unsequenced relative to everything between them.  A programmer who recognizes that compilers may do this could ensure that any compiler *that makes any effort whatsoever to look for evidence of aliasing* would see it.  Programmers and compiler writers might not know exactly how much evidence compilers should need...

Comment: ...but if programmers and compiler writers are both at least somewhat cautious there won't be any problem.  IMHO, any compiler that can't recognize that something like `int floatbits(float *fp) { return *(int*)fp;}` might actually access an object of type `float` should be regarded as willfully and obtusely blind.  Recognizing aliasing in such cases should be easy for any compiler whose design is well suited to low-level programming.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are targeting (presumably) an embedded platform with well-known characteristics and well-defined behavior, then you can make an informed decision to disable strict aliasing with `-fno-strict-aliasing`. Undefined behavior simply is non-portable behavior that if defined would preemptively pessimize certain systems.

If you *really* care about following the standard, using a union is your best bet. You could try to C++-ify it by going for some type of specialized type-safe union that doesn't perform any allocations or using some type of span/view class that can accept a pointer to a char buffer, but wraps your POD-specific API.

Comment: I was not actually targeting an embedded platform. This is a database application where some program outside the database engine may have to process the results of queries that return millions or even billions of rows. We have access to the source code of the database, but running the processing inside the engine is not a viable solution for security reasons.